# Variable length-encoding of int to 2 bytes

Tags: java, int, byte, primitive

I'm implementing variable lenght encoding and reading [***wikipedia***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity#Examples) about it. Here is what I found:

```
0x00000080  0x81 0x00
```

It mean `0x80` int is encoded as `0x81 0x00` 2 bytes. That what I cannot understand. Okay, following the algorithm listed there we have.

1. Binary  `0x80`: `00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000`
2. We move the sign bit to the next octet so we have and set to 1 (indicating that we have more octets): 
   `00000000 00000000 00000001 10000000` which is not equals to `0x81 0x00`. I tried to write a program for that:

   ```
   byte[] ba = new byte[]{(byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x00};
   int first = (ba[0] & 0xFF) & 0x7F;
   int second = ((ba[1] & 0xFF) & 0x7F) << 7;
   int result = first | second;
   System.out.println(result); //prints 1, not 0x80
   ```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/kB3ubS#stdin)

What did I miss?

Comment: I think you missed the example for the number 137 under the heading Examples. It is very clear. I'm not sure why you're mentioning a sign bit in step 2 as your number is either unsigned or a positive twos complement number, so there is no issue of a sign bit. There is a MSB (most significant bit) in each byte which is used to indicate whether another byte follows. Each byte encodes 7 bits from the original.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt But I used this example to convert `0x80` to variable length encoding. `0x80 = 10000000`, the lowest 7 bits = `0000000` and significant bytes = **0**0000000. So eventually we have 0000000**1** **0**0000000 != 0x81 . Really don't understand the mistake...

Comment: You forgot the fourth bullet point on wikipedia, the highest bit which indicates that another byte will follow: **1**0000001 00000000

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Btw, [this resource](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/fileformats.html#VInt) says that `0x80` != `0x81 0x00`...

Comment: Your resource is LSB first, whereas the Wikipedia example is MSB first. There's your difference. Just reverse the order of the lower, middle and upper 7-bit parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's review the algorithm from the Wikipedia page:

1. Take the binary representation of the integer
2. Split it into groups of 7 bits, the group with the highest value will have less
3. Take these seven bits as a byte, setting the MSB (most significant bit) to 1 for all but the last; leave it 0 for the last one

We can implement the algorithm like this:

```
public static byte[] variableLengthInteger(int input) {
    // first find out how many bytes we need to represent the integer
    int numBytes = ((32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(input)) + 6) / 7;
    // if the integer is 0, we still need 1 byte
    numBytes = numBytes > 0 ? numBytes : 1;
    byte[] output = new byte[numBytes];
    // for each byte of output ...
    for(int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++) {
        // ... take the least significant 7 bits of input and set the MSB to 1 ...
        output[i] = (byte) ((input & 0b1111111) | 0b10000000);
        // ... shift the input right by 7 places, discarding the 7 bits we just used
        input >>= 7;
    }
    // finally reset the MSB on the last byte
    output[0] &= 0b01111111; 
    return output;
}
```

You can see it working for the examples from the Wikipedia page [here](https://tio.run/##nZRRT8IwEMef56e48GDaEKCgEeIUE00aTTQ@GF80PHRS53R0pO1Qo3x2vK5jIGji3Et317v//e7a7VnMRCubSvU8flkspnmUJg/wkApj4EokCj52gtJprLC4zLJkDBPcIjdWJyq@H4HQsaEuMpiix57LNzITOhFRKi@liu3ThbIylpqwN1Y@lIbQ6YBz/D2tz6u0Pv972mBVbdCtVbK3TnrGauXucb7C5bwW8/563YJ5UKd4l/Ot4rUIet/PaEVQB2OwcdJn7D8qnP/WTNXR/McrWklH71biJXVLeUsfM01wExI49u52WpSFFnRD9A6PgeHaalEMDm7ejZWTdpbbdqFJSrq2zVDefwTkFGXQcatMEis5xpCirrlPRpRCExrQoOHOtliqiPNvtVBC/zyWgl1Nc@vbcabKJw7BYEeE7PWwkyUl7kRSXz9eSjFG0jupM0N8tgM7oNCBvkNbk6heh8DgZGUe4nwwsoTDJlDFhctXD7wMHIUbU3bjhKNKCK1m08MHXgXn5NCdCsUOCj7YBRZ1/UPh0xnLv4fTD3zQEE@r4McZLsXYCHaxaMTK7BBwT0uba1VSFzOfLxZf), you can also plug in your own values and try it online.

Answer (score 2):

Another Variable length encoding of integers exists and are widely used. For example ASN.1 from 1984 does [define "length" field](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/a-warm-welcome-to-asn1-and-der/#length) as:

> The encoding of length can take two forms: short or long. The short
> form is a single byte, between 0 and 127.
>
> The long form is at least two bytes long, and has bit 8 of the first
> byte set to 1. Bits 7-1 of the first byte indicate how many more bytes
> are in the length field itself. Then the remaining bytes specify the
> length itself, as a multi-byte integer.

This encoding is used for example in DLMS COSEM protocol or https certificates. For simple code, you can have a look at [ASN.1 java library](https://github.com/beanit/asn1bean/blob/master/projects/asn1bean/src/main/java/com/beanit/asn1bean/ber/BerLength.java#L31).